# How to update dart SDK to latest stable version in flutter

Tags: intellij-idea, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app, dart

I would like to use dart SDK: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0" with flutter. But my current version of dart used by Flutter is 2.5.0.

After tried `flutter upgrade` my flutter version is:

```
flutter --version 
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 68587a0916 (3 months ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
```

I have tried to download the latest stable release of Flutter SDK(2.6.1) from the [link](https://dart.dev/tools/sdk/archive) and replace it with the already available dart-sdk inside **flutter > bin > cache > dart-sdk** but after this steps I am getting below error:

```
Wrong full snapshot version, expected 'cb187597a166f2c0c64a200e22509ee3' found 'c8562f0ee0ebc38ba217c7955956d1cb' 

Isolate creation failed
```

Is there any other way to solve these issues and upgrade dart-sdk in flutter?

Comment: Switch to one of the other channels: see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels (you are on stable). At the moment, master is already on Dart 2.7. Try beta first, then dev.

Comment: Yeah, @RichardHeap I switched to the flutter-dev channel and It is already on dart 2.7 and flutter 1.12.16.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter only supports Dart 2.5 rigth now. There is now way to support 2.6. You will have to wait for a new Flutter release to support newer versions of Dart.